# Switching values from 2 columns

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script that reads an Excel sheet.

In my excel sheet I have two columns, let's say A & B.

If column B's value is greater than column A I would like to switch it.

 
Example Sheet:

```
[A]     [B]
 1       6
 10      2
 3       11
```

Output Wanted:

```
[A]     [B]
 6       1
 10      2
 11      3
```

Right now I have this, but it is giving me completely different values:

```
s = (~(col['A'] < col['B'])).cumsum().eq(0)
col.loc[s, 'B'] /=2
col.loc[s, 'A'] = col.loc[s, ['A', 'B']].sum(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Pandas based on your syntax.  This would be a good situation for using the DataFrame.apply() method.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 10, 3], 'B': [6, 2, 11]})

def switch(row):
    if row['A'] < row['B']:
        row['A'], row['B'] = row['B'], row['A']
    return row
df = df.apply(switch, axis=1)
print(df)
```

gives:

```
    A  B
0   6  1
1  10  2
2  11  3
```

Comment: Can DataFrame read Excel sheet columns? For example the rows in each column are lengthy so I cannot just store it in a single bracket list. So if my excel sheet is named mySheet can I do mySheet['A']? in the DataFrame

Comment: Yes it can.  I would point you towards the Pandas documention.  You can read in an excel file simply by using the pd.read_excel('path/to/excel.xlsb') method.